# Excel like groupping in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following pandas `DataFrame`:

```
DataFrame({'var1': ['a','a','e','d','d','d','a','a','b','b']}, index=range(1,11))

    var1
1   a
2   a
3   e
4   d
5   d
6   d
7   a
8   a
9   b
10  b
```

And I need to add variable `group_id` which increments by one when new sequence of the same letters emerges. The same letter may be in the many sequences. In Excel I can create formulas and fill the column. The value will be incremented if new letter in the row shows.

So the desired result is

```
idx var1    group_id
1    a          0
2    a          0
3    e          1
4    d          2
5    d          2
6    d          2
7    a          3
8    a          3
9    b          4
10   b          4
```

What is the best way to do it in python pandas?

Comment: Does `df['group_id'] = (df['var1'] != df['var1'].shift()).cumsum()` work? And, you can subtract 1 if you want to start with zero.

Comment: yes, that's OK for me